# How can I ignore an operator overload

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I am implementing IComparible with

```
public int CompareTo(RangeEx range)
{
    if (range == null)
                return 1;
// more stuff
}

public static bool operator ==(RangeEx x, RangeEx y) { return x.CompareTo(y) == 0; }
```

The problem is the "if (range == null)" calls the operator overload. How can I do the check for null by not calling the overload?

Comment: You cannot do that, instead you must fix your operator code so that it can safely handle `null` references. Or you can change your if-statement, try `if (range is null)` instead, assuming you're on C# 7, or you can do `if (ReferenceEquals(range, null))`.

Comment: `if (ReferenceEquals(range, null))` is the standard correct way of doing this.